# How to scrape http://gigs.gigatools.com/user/Danny/archive

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape http://gigs.gigatools.com/user/Danny/archive using python and beautifulsoup!How can I make date and month available as a variable for every listing for months with more that one event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the month div doesn't contain the dates divs so you have to go through them sequentially and change the month value when you get to the next month independent of how many gigs there were.  Here is my solution:

```
url='http://gigs.gigatools.com/user/Danny/archive'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

events=soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'events'})
month = ""
day = ""
number = ""
for div in events.findAll('div'):
    try:
        if(div.get("class")[0] == "monthLeft"):
            month = div.text.strip()
        if(div.get("class")[0] == "day"):
            day = div.text.strip()
        if(div.get("class")[0] == "number"):
            number = div.text.strip()
            print (month + " " + day + " " + number)
    except:
        day = ""
```

This produces the following output:

```
NOVEMBER '15 SATURDAY 7
OCTOBER '15 THURSDAY 1
SEPTEMBER '15 MONDAY 21
SEPTEMBER '15 SATURDAY 19
SEPTEMBER '15 THURSDAY 17
SEPTEMBER '15 FRIDAY 11
SEPTEMBER '15 MONDAY 7
SEPTEMBER '15 THURSDAY 3
AUGUST '15 FRIDAY 28
AUGUST '15 MONDAY 24
.....
```

Comment: Thanks,your answer solved my problem!